# Executing a Perl script on Java button ActionEvent

Tags: perl, user-interface

I'm trying to run a Perl script when I push a button on a JFrame.  I read around and realize that I need to use Runtime.exec() to run a command, and this works in the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Charts {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:/Users/ryanm/Documents/updateCharts.pl");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println (e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I place this code in the ActionEvent for a button on a jframe it doesn't work:

```
import java.io.IOException;
...
...
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:/Users/ryanm/Documents/updateCharts.pl");
        System.out.println ("Execute");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println (e.toString());
    }
}                                        
...
...
```

The print statement in the try block prints out when I click the button, so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What *doesn't work*? What happens?

Comment: The script doesn't run.  "Execute" is printed to the terminal, and no error messages are thrown, but the script doesn't execute.

Comment: You can try catching `Exception` to get all the exceptions, not just IO, and also try getting an exit value from the executed process using [`Process.exitValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()).

Comment: I added a check for process.exitValue() == 0 and it passed.  I also changed it to check for all exceptions but it didn't throw anything...

Comment: Oh yeah, it did print the "Execute" before, so no exceptions. Okay, no more ideas for now, sorry :)